# In Bootstrap, how do I keep all my elements on the same row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/t5sbzdxr/

I have consecutive elements between `<div></div>` tags but they all appear on different rows:

[image]

The relevant code is:

```
           <div class="col-10 d-inline">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline" style="width: 40px;"> <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline"> days </label>
              <select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-2" style="width:210px">
                 <option value="each">each </option>
              </select>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto"> My Button </button>
           </div>
```

How do I get all my elements to appear on the same row?

Edit: for clarification, I'm not interested in having the elements left justified ie sitting flush with each other. I would like to have all the elements in a single row.

Comment: what exactly does your fiddle show?? and where is your code?? so that we can figure out the problem

Comment: My mistake. Edited to show correct fiddle.

Comment: You need to use 3 columns in the same row. If you use only 1 column the elements will appear on top of each other. This is how HTML works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that, your select has width of 210px and has display block (it tries to be on its row) so you either make it `display:inline` and do something about its width, or you can simply make the parent div, display flex (the first solution is prefered)

Answer (score 1):

for `col-10` I used `d-flex` instead of `d-inline`

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal-content pl-3 pr-3">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body-scrolled border-primary border-bottom p-0 mt-2">
      <div>
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-2"></div>
          <div class="col-10 d-flex">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline" style="width: 40px;"> <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm d-inline"> days </label>
            <select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm ml-2" style="width:210px">
                     <option value="each">each </option>
                  </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto"> My Button </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/) for inline forms. Here is your code:

```
<div class="modal-content pl-3 pr-3">
   <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-body-scrolled p-0 mt-2">
         <div class="form-inline">
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm d-inline" style="width: 40px;">                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm ml-2 d-inline"> days</label>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group mx-sm-5">
             <select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:210px">
               <option value="each">each </option>
             </select>
           </div>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">My Button</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/032oawv9/

Answer (score 0):

Remove this Class `ml-2`

```
<select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:210px">
       <option value="each">each </option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vpLk90xb/

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some changes add `display:inline-block;margin: 0 10px;` and remove class `ml-2` from select element

```
<select type="field" class="form-control form-control-sm " style="width:210px;display:inline-block;margin: 0 10px;">
                     <option value="each">each </option>
                  </select>
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/copyb367/